Identify District Automatically, based on County selection
I have a SharePoint List that includes a column with drop down options for counties with a specific Region. I would like to add another column that auto populates the associated District, based on the County selected.
For example:
Rockland County is selected, Hudson Valley District automatically appears.
Albany County is selected, Capital District automatically appears.
And so on.
What would be the most efficient way to achieve this?
Thank you in advance!!

Based on your post, I understand that you want to create a Cascade dropdown list in SharePoint online.
Here are three methods to achieve this:
1.SharePoint Lists
2.Column formatting (JSON)
3.Power Apps (Filter, Choice)
Please refer this article to implement.
